# Applying a git stash created with --all

Tags: git, git-stash

I accidentally created a git stash with the `--all` option, which, according to the docs,

> If the `--all` option is used instead then the ignored files are stashed and cleaned in addition to the untracked files.

So now restoring my changes with `git stash pop` fails:

```
some/ignored/file already exists, no checkout
Could not restore untracked files from stash
```

(What I actually should have done is use `--include-untracked`)

`git stash show -p` still lists my changes, without any ignored files. How can I `apply` my stash without git trying to restore ignored files?

**Edit**: I just created a test repository and did a `git stash --all`. Ignored files were stashed and removed from the file system. My problem is that in my case above, they were stashed, but **not** removed from the file system, so that seems to be the cause for the problem.

Comment: Why do you not want to restore ignored files?

Comment: I don't, I created the stash with the wrong arguments and now git wants to restore ignored files as well. I don't care about the ignored files.

Comment: What if you delete the ignored files from the workbench and then try to pop from the stash? It should work...

Comment: That's true, but I suppose there has to be a proper way to do this. It's not the case for me, but ignored files might have changed since creating the stash, and you don't want to lose those changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use log to find the commit hash of your stash

```
$ git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline
```

All is important because it also shows stashes

It should look similar to this

```
*-.   cd5e9ae (refs/stash) WIP on master: cd48088 Fixed GET chats output
|\ \  
| | * e48d0d7 untracked files on master: cd48088 Fixed GET chats output
| * 1a3bf97 index on master: cd48088 Fixed GET chats output
|/  
* cd48088 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Fixed GET chats output
```

Now, you want to checkout the top of the stash (here, it's cd5e9ae)

```
$ git checkout cd5e9ae
```

You will be in a detached HEAD state
reset it one step back, keeping the changes

```
$ git reset HEAD~1
```

and now stash it like you meant to

```
$ git stash --include-untracked
```

Now you can go back to master or wherever you were working and apply that new correct stash

```
$ git checkout master
$ git stash pop
```

Inspired by [this blog post](http://blog.tfnico.com/2012/09/git-stash-blooper-could-not-restore.html)

I just tested it and it worked in my project with my ignored files, it should work for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete those files in order to pop the stash. You can do it manually or you can follow this method:

```
git stash -all  # make a new stash           
git stash pop stash@{1}  # apply your original stash
```

If you like it, you can drop the new stash you have done:

```
git stash drop
```

Comment: See OP comment above: *That's true, but I suppose there has to be a proper way to do this. It's not the case for me, but ignored files might have changed since creating the stash, and you don't want to lose those changes.*

Comment: `git stash -u` will not delete those files, because as I said, they are ignored.

Comment: Than he should backup/move them.

Comment: @amiuhle do `git stash -all`

Comment: But that's what I originally did! Ignored files ended up in the stash, but weren't deleted from the file system.

Comment: Okay, I see that this should work - maybe the real problem/question is why ignroed files were added to the stash but not removed from the file system...

Comment: If those ignored/untracked files are important for you, you should backup them, do your stash pop and than recover them.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns's answer worked, so I accepted it. Upvoted this one, too because it should also work, had my ignored files been removed when stashing...